# click save button on explorer download popup

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate getting a file from a web page. It opens the Save Download window with the 3 usual choices (Open, Save, and Cancel). I'm trying to click on the Save button but can't get it to work. I even tried to get the `&Save` handle from Spy++ and inserting the handle pointer just before executing `ClickButton` just to be sure I had the right handle pointer and still nothing.

Everything works fine except for `SendMessage(WindowHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, IntPtr.Zero)`

```
Sub ClickButton(ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr)
    'SendMessageW(WindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, New IntPtr(WA_ACTIVE), IntPtr.Zero) I've tried several flavors of this ClickButton and no effect! 
    'SendMessageW(WindowHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    SendMessage(WindowHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub


Sub LookForAndCloseIEPopup()
    'get a handle to any popup window associated with the main form (as is a popup window
    'displayed by the Web browser control)...
    Dim ptrDialogWindow As IntPtr = GetWindow(xAsIntPtr, GW_ENABLEDPOPUP)
    Dim text2 = GetWindowText(xAsIntPtr)
    If text2.Contains("File Download") Then
        'xAsIntPtr = hWnd
        'LookForAndCloseIEPopup() '(GetWindowText(hwnd, text, Int16.MaxValue))
    End If

    Debug.Print(GetWindowText(ptrDialogWindow) & "TEXT:=" & Text2 & vbCrLf)
    'if the popup window is one displayed by the browser, then send the close message to the window...
    If text2.Contains("File Download") Then ClosePopup(ptrDialogWindow)

End Sub

Sub ClosePopup(ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr)

    Dim clsChildHandles As ArrayList = GetChildWindowHandles(WindowHandle)
    Dim teststr As String
    Dim prthandleint As Long
    'look through all of the child handles of the window for an "OK" button (this method 
    'can also be used to gather more specific information about the dialog itself, such as 
    'the message being displayed)...
    For Each ptrHandle As IntPtr In clsChildHandles
        'if the OK button is found, click it...
        teststr = GetWindowText(ptrHandle)
        prthandleint = ptrHandle
        'ptrHandle = &H002A0B7E    !!! I even tried putting the &Save handle which I got from Spy++ with the same result! 
        Debug.Print(GetWindowText(ptrHandle) & " = Child TEXT:   len=" & teststr.Length & "handle = " & prthandleint & vbCrLf)

        If teststr.Contains("&Save") Then
            ClickButton(ptrHandle)  'This part works fine as I get here
            Exit For
        Else
            Debug.Print(GetWindowText(ptrHandle) & " = Child TEXT:   len=" & vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Const WM_GETTEXT As Long = &HD
Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Long = &HE
Const GW_ENABLEDPOPUP As Long = 6
Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&
Const GW_CHILD As Long = 5
Const GW_HWNDNEXT As Long = 2
Const WM_ACTIVATE As Integer = &H6
Const WA_ACTIVE As Integer = &H1
'function to retrieve the popup window associated with the form, as well as to find the child windows of the popup...
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageW")>
Private Shared Function SendMessageW(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
'sendmessage overload that is used to send messages to the button on the dialog window...
Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessage" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer,
ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

'sendmessage overloads used to retrieve the window text...
Private Declare Auto Function SendMessageA Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer,
ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint:="SendMessage")> Public Shared Function SendMessageString(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wparam As Integer, ByVal lparam As System.Text.StringBuilder) As IntPtr
End Function
Function GetChildWindowHandles(ByVal ParentWindowHandle As IntPtr) As ArrayList

    Dim b As Boolean
    Dim ptrChild As IntPtr
    Dim clsRet As New ArrayList
    'ParentWindowHandle = IntPtr(xAsIntPtr)
    'get first child handle...
    ptrChild = GetChildWindowHandle(xAsIntPtr)

    Do Until ptrChild.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)
        'add to collection of handles...
        clsRet.Add(ptrChild)
        'get next child...
        ptrChild = GetNextWindowHandle(ptrChild)

    Loop

    'return...
    Return clsRet

End Function

Function GetChildWindowHandle(ByVal ParentWindowHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Return GetWindow(ParentWindowHandle, GW_CHILD)
End Function

Function GetNextWindowHandle(ByVal CurrentWindowhandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Return GetWindow(CurrentWindowhandle, GW_HWNDNEXT)
End Function

'this function returns the text of the window, used so that we can confirm that we have the right dialog window...
Function GetWindowText(ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr) As String

    Dim ptrRet As IntPtr
    Dim ptrLength As IntPtr

    'get length for buffer...
    ptrLength = SendMessageA(WindowHandle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

    'create buffer for return value...
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(ptrLength.ToInt32 + 1)

    'get window text...
    ptrRet = SendMessageString(WindowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, ptrLength.ToInt32 + 1, sb)

    'get return value...
    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

In the debug output window I see the value of `&Save` get captured and the code works as expected up to the part where `ClickButton` tries to execute with a non response.

Comment: Can you instead download this resource using HttpClient/WebRequest/WebClient?

Comment: If you know the file URL than you can use this very simple code to download the file using VB.NET code. My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
    "https://abc/demo_img.png",
    "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\247.png") Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-download-a-file

Comment: The download happens when I click on 'export to excel' then I get the usual Save Download popup box with the three buttons!  Open Save and Cancel!

Comment: There is no webservice available for this site!

Comment: Instead of clicking on `export to excel`, take the underlying link and save to a file the resource it points to using one of the mentioned classes (often WebClient in these case). If you can post the Uri of the html page you're referring to it may be easier to suggest a different approach.

Comment: Also, note that it's quite possible that after clicking on the dialog's `Save` button, a `Save File` common dialog will appear, to let the User specify the destination path of the file.

Comment: The excel file is built when you click on the export to excel tab! So the only choice I have is to find a way to click on the save button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself!

Needed to put setactiveWindow in first!

```
    SetActiveWindow(xAsIntPtr)
    SendMessageW(WindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, New IntPtr(WA_ACTIVE), IntPtr.Zero)
    SendMessageW(WindowHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Pete