# Accessing buttons on the Internet Explorer 11 View downloads form

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sendmessage, findwindow

I have a piece of code in vb.net to open a web link for an application and to download a file from the page. The web browser loads the page and the program auto clicks the link on the page to download the file which then makes the "View Downloads - Internet Explorer" window in IE 11 to pop up as shown below:

[Internet Explorer 11- VIew Downloads window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu1JU.png)

I managed to activate the window but not able to click the Save button to automatically download the file without user intervention. The code that I tried to activate and  click the button is as below

```
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal WindowTitle As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" (ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal WindowTitle As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr


Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim ParentWndHandle As IntPtr
    ParentWndHandle = FindWindow("#32770", "View Downloads - Internet Explorer")
    If ParentWndHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        Dim ChildWndHandle As IntPtr
        ChildWndHandle = FindWindowEx(ParentWndHandle, vbNullString, "DirectUIHWND", vbNullString)
        Dim btn1 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(ChildWndHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save")
        SendMessage(ChildWndHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, 0)
        SendMessage(ChildWndHandle, WM_COMMAND, VK_RETURN, IntPtr.Zero)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564866/click-save-button-on-explorer-download-popup): You need to use `SetActiveWindow` before `SendMessage`.

Or can you extract the file url? If so, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-download-a-file) to use the simple `DownloadFile` method to download files:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
    "http://www.example.com/downloads/abc.txt",
    "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\abc.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my query. The file url is not available moreover the data in the downloaded file varies based on the date parameters passed onto it. In the thread mentioned in your reply, the variable xAsIntPtr is not assigned any value and it is also unclear which function is invoked first.

Comment: I think you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setactivewindow) and [this link](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetActiveWindow.html) about how to use `SetActiveWindow` function. The parameter passed in should be the handle to the window you want to active.